# Quicktime won't install on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, quicktime

I am trying to install quicktime (actually just need iTunes..but then iTunes needs qt), but it fails. There seems to be a problem with the folder C:\Program Files(x86)\QuickTime\ - Quick Time wants to write the file QTTask.exe, but complains that it does not have permission to do so. Same thing happens with \PropertyPanels\PanelHelperBase.qpa

I have tried deleting all Apple programs (in the order suggested in the support forum) and also tried to delete the temp folder. That did not work. 
I have tried to manually adjust the permissions of the QuickTime folder - no effect.

I have run the installation file with admin rights and with different compatibility modes to no effect.

I consider myself to be an experienced user - able to solve most problems - but now I am stuck. I need some input / fresh ideas on how to tackle the problem.

This is very annoying as I cannot sync iPhone/iPad/iPod while iTunes is not running - due to the stupid (*sorry*) idea of only have your device linked to one library.

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: Tried installing it elsewhere? Such as Program Files/ (as opposed to Program Files(x86)/ )?

Comment: If you don't like iTunes, you do know there are other softwares that CAN do iDevice sync right?  (I only say this because I get the impression you'd like an alternative.)

Comment: There is different software? I didnt know that. Can it also grap podcasts from iTunes and install apps and stuff?

Comment: I tried to install in Program Files, but it just doesn't do it. Also tried to create a symlink - which did not take care of the problem.

Comment: I made a screenshot of Process Monitor, where I think it goes wrong... any suggestions? http://screencast.com/t/diysDzJOVazK

Comment: Also this: http://screencast.com/t/vnjXbvL5

Comment: QT doesn't come in 64bit, only iTunes does (as well as 32bit). QT is only 32bit.

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that came to my mind was to make sure that you have the x64 installer and not the x86 or even x86-64 installer.

Comment: Thank you! I did download the newest x64 version from the Apple site. It seems that quicktime is the problem where it gets ugly. I can install the standalone version of iTunes x64 just fine, but there is no x64 version of quicktime.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it would not install. Quicktime uninstall would crash. I deleted everything Apple and Quicktime from my pc from folders to registry entries and I got it to install, but it would not launch, would crash. I had a thought... I uninstalled Ace Mega Codec pack and my problems went away. Apparently it was interferring with install and launch.
 The codec pack installs some quicktime codecs that stopped the installer. I hope this helps someone out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [QTLite](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/QT_Lite.htm) to replace QuickTime. The current version is a bit old (released in December), but it uses a much simpler installer.